# Should metrics calls be awaited? Is it safe to not await them?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, metrics, fire-and-forget

In my backend web service, metrics are sent at multiple moments to keep track of its behavior. To send a metric, I do an http call. I fear that awaiting it adds useless latency to the responses of the service. To me, it seems they should be fire and forget. Is it safe and/or recommended to not await those kinds of calls?

Note: My service is in c#, dotnet core.

PS: Call failures could be logged by the metrics package itself. A failure of a metrics call should not break the user call.

Comment: Do you care if a call fails?

Comment: No. The metrics package can log on failures, but it should not break the call to the service.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need it why await.
But be careful abbout errors.

Here are some extensions to help with errors

```
public static void RunAndForget(this Task task, Action<Exception> onError)
{
    task.ContinueWith(t => { onError?.Invoke(t.Exception); }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}

//the Logging.LogException is a static Action so you can set it once
public static void RunAndForget(this Task task)
{
    task.ContinueWith(t => { Logging.LogException(t.Exception); }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind the `onError` handler or `LogException()` could themselves throw an exception (despite the fact that best practice is to implement no-throw loggers).

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not it's safe to fire and forget the call depends on the metrics library's implementation and potentially the error handling (e.g. logging). The forgotten task can keep executing after its parent HTTP request context gets disposed and if the task tries to use a disposed resource it could crash.

Whether or not you'll run into problems depends on the specific components and how they're configured, for example if the task's dependencies rely on the garbage collector for cleanup then you're OK. However if ASP.NET DI container calls `Dispose()` on the task's dependency then that dependency can start throwing `InvalidOperationException`.